# In ConTeXt, how can I avoid \underbar also underlining a following dash?

Tags: context, underline

In this code:

```tex
\starttext
  \underbar{foo}-bar
\stoptext
```

ConTeXt also underlines the dash after `foo` instead of just underlining `foo`. How can I fix that?

Comment: What version are you using? In latest LMTX it works fine

Comment: @JairoA.delRio I'm using MacTeX 2020. ConTeXt version is `2020.03.10 14:44`. Will update everything and check if that fixes it.

Comment: In the meantime, you could add `\zwj`, `\kern0pt` or another possibility, but they are only workarounds. I'll ask to the mailing list

Comment: @JairoA.delRio `\zwj` works and I'd accept it as answer since updating MacTeX did not bring a new ConTeXt version. Might eventually switch to installing ConTeXt standalone besides MacTeX but I don't fancy it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bug, as ConTeXt LMTX (version `2021.03.09 11:42`) gives the correct result (right):

[image]
[image]

I've already sent a [message to the mailing list](https://www.mail-archive.com/ntg-context@ntg.nl/msg97847.html) to report this issue.

In the meantime, among other alternatives, a `\zwj` (zero-width joiner) counts as a workaround.

```
\starttext
\underbar{foo}\zwj-bar
\stoptext
```